# how do I exclude user defined exceptions in the visual studio 2010 debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a web application where I attach the visual studio debugger. I am trying to locate a specific problem and it keeps stopping on exceptions I do not care about.

I have managed to uncheck the .NET exceptions by going to `Debug->Exceptions`. However when I add the name of the exception from the third party tool, I cannot keep it from stopping on those exceptions.

What am I doing wrong? The exceptions dialog wouldn't have a place to add exceptions if they didn't expect you to add your own, would it?

Comment: Unchecking "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in that dialog should be enough.  Are you sure these are not unhandled exceptions?  The debugger will always stop on those.

Comment: I guess it could be unhandled. We have a last stop handler for exceptions so that any are caught, but I can't say for certain that none ever slip through the cracks.

Comment: Did you copy paste the full name of the exception?

Comment: @Omer Raviv - that fixed the problem. I was only adding the class name. Adding the full name and then unchecking it keeps it from stopping on that exception, like I expected. Add your suggestion as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the fullly qualified name of the Exception (ie, include the namespace) when you add an exception to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by going to `Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> General -> "Enable Just My Code"`. This will cause debugger to stop at only your code.

Comment: I don't want it to stop at all for these specific exceptions. However I do want it to stop for any other exceptions, whether it be for my code or not.

Comment: What type of exceptions are they? If you go to `Debug > Exceptions` you can customize it not break on certain types.

Comment: Yes I know, I said I was doing that in my question. I cannot figure out how to add ones that are not already there.

Comment: they are ResourceNotFoundException exceptions from some nvelocity templates that I do not have. I don't care about those. I'm trying to debug something completely unrelated, but I don't know where the problem is so I need to catch everything else.

Comment: I never tried it, but I guess you can go to `Debug > Exceptions > Add` and add those exceptions `[namespace].[classname].[ExceptionName]`. Then _uncheck_ those. It kinda taking the other way round, but if it works... !

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Omer Raviv is right: Specify the fully qualified name of the exception!

Just to make clear how the Exception-Window in VS 2010 should look like, here is a screenshot of a user defined exception that will not be stopped at while debugging:

[image]