# How do I change the default list of exceptions shown in Visual Studio's Exceptions dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

There is a certain C++ exception which I never want to stop for while debugging. I know I can add it to the list of Visual Studio exceptions, as described here: [how do I exclude user defined exceptions in the visual studio 2010 debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877449/how-do-i-exclude-user-defined-exceptions-in-the-visual-studio-2010-debugger)  ... and then uncheck it. Once I have added a new exception type to the list, is there some way I can save it, so it will be listed whenever I am using Visual Studio with any project/solution -- not just the one where I initially added it?

Comment: I don't have VS2010 installed anymore.  For VS2012 it is the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config\AD7Metrics\Exception\{3A12D0B7-C26C-11D0-B442-00A0244A1DD2}\C++ Exceptions registry key.  VS2010 is version 10.0

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. Just realized I actually meant a Win32 exception, which is a different subkey of the same Exception key. All I had to do is add a new subkey of Win32 Exceptions with an exception of my choice, then give it values Code and State, where Code is the value of the exception and State presumably has something to do with whether it is on by default -- most of them seem to default to 0xc.